# No appropriate default constructor available within googletest EXPECT_NO_THROW

Tags: c++, googletest

Declaration:

```
class ClassOne
{
    ClassOne (ClassTwo* classTwo, ClassThree const& classThree);
}
```

Test:

```
ClassTwo* classTwo;
ClassThree classThree;
EXPECT_NO_THROW (ClassOne (classTwo, classThree));
```

This compiles and runs, but now I change it to:

Declaration:

```
class ClassOne
{
    ClassOne (ClassThree const& classThree);
}
```

Test:

```
ClassThree classThree;
EXPECT_NO_THROW (ClassOne (classThree));
```

This fails with "no appropriate default constructor available".

The following lines compile:

```
ClassOne classOne (classTwo, classThree);    // First case
ClassOne classOne (classThree);    // Second case
```

Is there some reason why I can't `EXPECT_NO_THROW` on a constructor with one parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in gtest I think (although I'm no expert on macros).  `EXPECT_NO_THROW` ultimately expands to:

```
#define GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_(statement) \
  if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { statement; }
```

Your code compiles using VS2012RC if `statement` is wrapped in parentheses in the `if` body:

```
#define GTEST_SUPPRESS_UNREACHABLE_CODE_WARNING_BELOW_(statement) \
  if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { (statement); }
//                                         ^         ^
```

As a workaround, you can do:

```
EXPECT_NO_THROW ((ClassOne (classThree)));
```

Comment: Thank you - that does work.  I had already found that: "EXPECT_NO_THROW (new ClassOne (classThree));" worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have been bitten by C++'s [most vexing  parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).
The "statement" argument to the EXPECT_NO_THROW macro, `ClassOne (classThree)`, is **not a definition** of nameless `ClassOne` object whose constructor gets a `ClassThree` object named `classThree`. It is the **declaration** of a **default-constructed** `ClassOne` object, named `classThree`. It's the same as if you had written `EXPECT_NO_THROW (ClassOne classThree);` - the parens are optional.

See https://youtu.be/lkgszkPnV8g?t=1750

The solution (if you can use C++11) is to use uniform initialization:

`EXPECT_NO_THROW (ClassOne {classThree});`